# Best way to loop through a char array line by line

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a char array that contains a text file retrieved from the web.
What is the best way to loop through this buffer line by line and show each
line?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Assuming there are line endings in the array search for those and do what you will with the lines in between them.

Comment: I got nothing so far. I don't know which functions or anything to use so can't google it. newb here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since this is c++, turn your char array into a stringstream, then process it much like you would any other stream/file. 
Certainly doing this will let you call functions like getline().

```
string tmpstr(chararry,length); // length optional, but needed if there may be zero's in your data
istringstream is(tmpstr);

string line;
while (getline(is,line)) {
    // process line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example Richard, i didn't expect a code hand out haha. It is ok to mix char and string? I used string once before in a native app and got laughed at.

Comment: Using char arrays will get you laughed at more than using strings will. Strings are how we are supposed to handle bunches of chars.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is a good solution but incurs a cost in copying the char array into a temporary string.  This can be avoided by using Boost's `iostream` instead - this avoids copying the buffer while letting you treat it as any other stream.

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> stream(buffer, size);
```